# Browsing the sqllite3 database in Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

This simple thing isn't that simple it seems.

I have seemingly created a database, however I am getting some error in my insert statement, which I need to browse the database and the table to be able to debug, but boy does that introduce some challenges.

I have a Samsung S3, connected it to my Ubuntu and I have tried to do what is suggested in this thread.

[browse data in Android SQLite Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530548/browse-data-in-android-sqlite-database/6074364#6074364)

But none of it work.
I cant access the sqlite3 using adb. I can't access the database with the plugin.
I can't access the /data folder as the file browser doesn't let me open the folder.
And last but not least, I have downloaded an SQLite Browser App, but this app doesn't show my database.

I know the database is there, because my app can read a table I have created.

I haven't gotten any useful information from the developer site at Android either.
Need some guidance here.

**EDIT**

I get the following error in eclipse console when trying to connect using adb

```
[2013-10-15 22:43:42 - DeviceMonitor] Adb connection Error:EOF
[2013-10-15 22:43:42 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 1
[2013-10-15 22:43:43 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 2
```

Comment: Why did you add the java tag? This is not java related

Comment: why not post the error you are getting for your insert statement?

Comment: if everything fails you can run adb pull and inspect the db on your ubuntu

Comment: because I will need to get this working anyhow, and I can figure out the problem myself if I could just see the database

Comment: pskink: How exactly? I don't know the location of my db

Comment: adb pull data/data/your.package.name/databases/YourDBName.db

Comment: dymmeh: That didnt work. its says it doesnt exist

Comment: Do you have a rooted device? I *thought* you could access data/data without root but maybe not having root is preventing you

Comment: No I don't have a rooted device.

Answer (score 1):

The sqlite binary may or may not be present on the device. There are apps for browsing sqlite DBs (if they're in an accessible location, like the SD card).  eg "aSQLiteManager".

You can try to find binaries for sqlite to install on the device (I've seen them, but haven't tried)

Other ways are adb'ing in, and using run-as to run as your app (to gain permissions to your app's private data area), then copying files over to sd card etc as needed to copy off device for playing with in a local version of sqlite etc.

Comment: I have tried to find the binaries, did so and installed it, but got some error message when I tried to run it using adb. So you are saying, if I change the storage of my database, then I might be able to also view it? Guess I can change it to the sd card. Maybe thats better

Comment: True - if you can run the binary on the device, it still may not have permission to read your private files (same with any of the sql browser apps -- viz if your device is rooted, and other caveats). So, yes, one way is to write your DB files to the sdcard (but then anyone/thing can see your DB). May also try `adb shell`, then `run-as com.example.yourapp` (still in a shell) and then try to use sqlite (since you're still on command line) to open your DB. I haven't tried it, but may work.

Answer (score 0):

I had some times issues with inserting data into sqlite3 db in android. You can try to make same db @ windows and run the insert commands there. There is a tool called : Sqlite Browser for windows, u can download it from this link. http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/

just try it, it will help you with find errors.

Comment: This is not an option for me. I don't have windows, nor do I want it.

Comment: okay, well than u can try to find the right OS from here, http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/files/sqlitebrowser/2.0%20beta1/

its for mac & linux OS.